# In what dialects does "often" rhyme with "soften"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, pronunciation-vs-spelling, rhymes, spelling-pronunciations

I believe in most English dialects *soften* is pronounced without a **t** sound.  In some dialects, *often* is similar, but in others a *t* sound is quite evident in *often*.

I'm interested not only in which areas of the world fall into each camp, but also whether there has been a recent transition going on in the pronunciation of the *t*.  In the American dialect I grew up with, the *t* was silent, but in the last 10 or 15 years it seems to the *t* sound has become frequent.  It may even have become predominant, but perhaps my brain has only been registering the pronounced-t instances since they are dissonant to my ear. My impression comes mainly from American broadcast media.

Comment: I don't think this is a regional variation at all (though there may be some slight preferences in different dialects). It is more likely a pronunciation learned from the literal spelling (as noted in answers).

Comment: US Midwest -- I pronounce them about the same most of the time -- with the "T" essentially silent.  I may get a hint more "T" into "often", but not much.  I have encountered US born and raised folks (I'm thinking from the US southeast) who said "off-ten", though.

Comment: Relate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/27373

Comment: Agreed - here in South Africa in the 80s and 90s the T in often was always silent. But since about the 0ties, the T is being pronounced - probably as more kids learn English from American television instead of from the proper sources. (By the way, "0ties" is pronounces the same as "naugties")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For *often* [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/often) marks the pronunciation with T with an obelus (÷), [meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/MWOL%20Pronunciation%20Guide.pdf)

> indicates that many regard as unacceptable the pronunciation variant immediately following: nuclear \nü-kl-r, nyü-, ÷-ky-lr\

[The Random House dictionary says](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/often):

> *Often* was pronounced with a t -sound until the 17th century, when a pronunciation without the [t] came to predominate in the speech of the educated, in both North America and Great Britain, and the earlier pronunciation fell into disfavor. Common use of a spelling pronunciation has since restored the [t] for many speakers, and today  exist side by side. Although it is still sometimes criticized, often  with a [t] is now so widely heard from educated speakers that it has become fully standard once again.

[The Oxford Dictionary says](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1273037#m_en_us1273037):

> **Usage**
>   When pronouncing *often*, some speakers sound the t, saying /ˈôftən/; for others, it is silent, as in *soften, fasten, listen*. Either pronunciation is acceptable, although /ˈôfən /
>   is more common.

Comment: From a UK perspective, I must admit I've never encountered anyone with an opinion about one pronunciation being more "acceptable" than the other. I think they're just ideolectal variants.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm consistent about pronouncing the t or not. As a point of interest, *The Pirates of Penzance* requires "often" and "orphan" to be homophones for at least one and probably two characters.

Comment: @NeilCoffey I'm also UK, and I have always had the impression that only northern, working class peasants (like me) pronounce the 't', and that the proper, posh way is to pronounce it without.

Comment: @Mynamite That may have been true once upon a time, but not any more. I know lots of southerners who pronounce the 't'.

Answer (score 10):

I might **hasten** to add that **often** one **softens** one’s  final *t* in derived compounds, lest it be **fastened** on too tightly and thus become obtrusive enough that one might well expect to be **chastened** for it.

That is, compare *hasten* < *haste*, *often* < *oft*, *soften* < *soft*, *fasten* < *fast*, and *chasten* < *chaste*.  The addition of *-en* to a word ending in *-st* or *-ft* causes the *t* to be lost in elision. See also *christen* < *Christ*, *moisten* < *moist*. In all cases, the *t* disappears from pronunciation.

Regarding [*often*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130795), the *OED* says:

> > Pronunciation:
> >       Brit.  /ˈɒf(ə)n/ ,  /ˈɒft(ə)n/ , U.S.  /ˈɔf(ə)n/ ,  /ˈɑft(ə)n/
> >
> > Forms:  ME offen, ME offtyn, ME oftin, ME ofton, ME oftun, ME oftyn, ME oftyne, ME ouften, ME– often, 15 hofen, 15 hoften, 15 offten, 19– affin (*Irish English*), 19– aften (*Irish English*); *Sc*. pre-17 ofen, pre-17 oftin, pre-17 17– aften, pre-17 17– often, 18 af’en, 18– affen. Comparative ME oftynar, ME oftynner, ME– oftener, 16 ofner, 16–17 oftner, 17 offner, 17 off’ner; also *Sc*. pre-17 oftner, pre-17 oiftner, pre-17 17– aftener, 19– af’ner. Superlative 15 oftnest, 15 oftneste, 16– oftenest, 17 oft’nest; also *Sc*. 19– aftenest. (Show Less)
> >
> > Etymology:  < **ofte**, variant of **oft** *adv*. + *-(e)n*, probably after **selden**, variant of **seldom** *adv*. and *adj*.
> >
> > ***Often*** is less commonly used than *oft*  until the 16th cent. Several orthoepists of the 16th and 17th centuries, including Hart, Bullokar, Robinson, Gil, and Hodges, give a pronunciation with medial *-t-*. Others, including Coles, Young, Strong, and Brown, record a pronunciation without *-t-*, which, despite its use in the 16th cent. by Elizabeth I, seems to have been avoided by careful speakers in the 17th cent. (see E. J. Dobson *Eng. Pronunc.* 1500–1700 (ed. 2, 1968) II. §405). Loss of *t*  after *f*  occurs in other cases; compare *soften* v., and also *raft* n.1, *haft* n.1, etc. The pronunciation with *-t-*  has frequently been considered to be hypercorrection in recent times: see for example H. W. Fowler *Mod. Eng. Usage* (1926), s.v.

However, the histories of *listen* (< OE *lysna*, **hlysna*) and *glisten* (< OE *glisnian, glysnian*) are different.

Answer (score 9):

"Often" is an example of [spelling pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_pronunciation). The history of *often* is sort of conflicted but most of the sites I found via Google pointed away from pronouncing the word with a `/t/` sound.

Strangely, "soften" *also* falls into this category. The word is does not strictly have a `/t/` sound and is traditionally pronounced `ˈsôfən`. I did again see references to a spelling pronunciation that included a `/t/` but it was less common than those for "often".

To directly answer your question, "often" should nearly always rhyme with "soften". If you are going to pronounce one with a `/t/` than the other should be said with a `/t/` as well. And vice versa: If you leave the `/t/` out in one, you should do so in the other.

Answer (score 3):

While the DARE will probably show where in the US "often" is pronounced with a 't', in my experience (representing West Coast, South, Midwest, and South East usage), the 't' is normally silent. I do routinely hear the 't' in "often" in Canadian English, where it may be a regionalism.

Curiously, such speakers do not pronounce the 't' in "soften," but it's quite normal for some English speakers to have contrasting pairs where others have homophones (e.g., "caught" vs "cot").

Answer (score 2):

on Forvo.com there are 10 pronunciations of 'often'.  The only one with a hard T comes from Texas and has several downvotes...
http://www.forvo.com/word/often/#en

Relatively small sample size, but seems to follow what others are saying here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Australia the silent t is common for both *often* and *soften*. Hard t occurs for *often*, but is very rare in *soften*.

Answer (score 0):

In the north of Scotland where I grew up *often* had a silent T, but I find in Edinburgh there are occasional uses of *often* with a hard T - I have not done much analysis but it seems to be based on spoken sentence structure.

- I often see herons at this pond - silent T
- Often, you'll see herons at this pond - hard T

Answer (score 0):

I have come to believe that some (perhaps most) people who use the hard "t" pronunciation do it intentionally, thinking they are being more correct.  I'm tempted to gently confront them with the "how do you pronounce chasten and soften" question.

Comment: ... or they learned to speak from people who use the hard "t" pronunciation. This pronunciation has been around long enough there must be second- and third-generation people using it now.