# How should "often" be pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, silent-letters, spelling-pronunciations, derivational-morphology

I heard people saying "Of-fen" as well as "Of-ton".
Till now I have been using the first one but few days ago I had an interviewer who pronounced *often* "Of-Ton" while interviewing.

Comment: "Often" could be pronounced a variety of different ways depending on the speaker's native dialect, how tired or lazy they are, and so on.  Could you clarify a bit what you are interested in?

Comment: Often I have pronounced often as of-fun but was I right all this while. Should I start pronouncing it as Of-Ton or people will still be able to get me when I pronounce it as Of-fun. ;)

Comment: People will still understand you.  That's self-evident, they always have so far from what you say.  Different dialects pronounce it [ɒfən], [ɒftən] or even [ɒfʔn], and all the shades in between.

Comment: If you were William S. Gilbert, you presumably pronounced *often* [exactly the same way as you did orphan](http://math.boisestate.edu/gas/pirates/web_op/pirates13d.html), which I'm sure doesn't have a /t/ in it.

Comment: @Rhodri, i doubt that anyone actually has a /t/ in *often* as an unlearned pronunciation. Where the /t/ exists it seems to be a spelling pronunciation, a form of hypercorrection.

Comment: @JSBangs: I have heard it in circumstances where people are being careful about their diction.  Sometimes this is hypercorrection, I agree, as when someone is being terribly careful in a TV interview.  On other occasions (particular when singing) I'm less sure of that.  I'd certainly agree that I would naturally use a glottal, and London-born friends drop even that.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ You have the right of it. But take care where you say that, lest you suffer the same fate as our brave heroine in my answer below. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 't' used to be pronounced, but then was lost, but the pronunciation with a 't' is slowly coming back (because of the spelling).

Dictionaries will provide the 't' pronunciation as a variant. Note that 'soften' is always pronounced without the 't' currently.

Comment: It'd be weird to put a hard consonant sound in the word `soften`. ♪

Comment: This sounds interesting. I never ever thought that I have been pronouncing Soften often as Sof-tun.

Comment: I think it's more that the 't' in "soften" mutated into a very soft glottal.

Comment: I don't think it has been lost in BE - I would say 't' is the normal British pronounciation

Comment: @Martin: I hear AmE speakers say both. And an AmE dictionary confirms that the without 't' is standard, and that with 't' is a common accepted variant.

Comment: @Mitch - I meant often was often pronounced with a 't' in BE - not soften

Comment: @GraceNote Thank you: you have been a true inspiration for me, the muse behind my rhyme. See below.  :)

Answer (score 12):

The true answer to this question is perhaps best explained by *The Ballad of Shameless Enjambment*, a cautionary tale here reproduced by kind permission of its author:

> From far and wide, they’ve come to list-
>         en, watch, and judge her plea.
> Beneath the lights her skin aglist-
>         en drips and drabbles free.
> Before she speaks she stops to moist-
>         en lips all cracked and dry;
> Refreshed for now, she lifts her voice
>         and pleading asks them, “Why?”  
> She tells them just how much, how oft-
>         en all well-spoken men
> That certain t’s they oft would soft-
>         en up, and how and when.
> This once a trait of working class
>         infects its rulers too,
> Who know no better than to fast-
>         en t’s where once taboo.  
> The scholars gasp, that she should chast-
>         en men of such renown.
> They rise as one and move to hast-
>         en towards her dressing down.
> But wait! she cries, there’s more to this
>         and other matters yet.
> Too late! they rage, and quick she’s christ-
>         ened fraudulent coquette.

Answer (score 6):

Majoring in languages and linguistics in college, I had one linguistics professor who was exceptionally adamant that *often* should **not** be pronounced with the *t*. That was a spelling pronunciation that had begun in the first quarter of the 20<sup>th</sup> century when greater access to schooling and literacy became available to children and adults. *Often* should be pronounced to rhyme with *soften*, this professor taught, as the two words had come through the language to modern times sharing the same etymological history — and we don’t pronounce the *t* in *soften*.

Comment: Exactly right, alas.

Answer (score 6):

The pronunciation with the 't' is a hypercorrection. Although the 't' was long ago pronounced, it has been silent for centuries and is only recently making a comeback because people assume that not pronouncing the 't' is erroneous. It makes sense that it would be silent, by analogy to similar words that lose their 't' sound when -(e)n is added ('soft'/'soften', 'list'/'listen', 'fast'/'fasten', 'haste'/'hasten', and of course, 'oft'/'often').

Comment: Could you please provide a source (such as a dictionary entry) confirming that these pronunciations without the _t_ are regarded as standard?

Comment: @TheodoreBroda any dictionary will give the 't-less' pronunciation for all of these as standard.

Answer (score 2):

The nuns taught it without pronouncing the *t*.  These nuns would emphasize their teaching with sharp and painful raps to our knuckles with a ruler. I would hate to think that all those bruised knuckles were for naught!

Comment: Indeed, they were chastening you.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best reference on the "t" is how we pronounce the word "soften," basically the same word as "often". YOU DON'T PRONOUNCE the "t"!