# In which varieties of English is 't' in 'often' silent?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm from India and all my life I've pronounced 'often' with 't' silent. Since we follow British English, I assume British people say it the same way? I guess in American English, one pronounces it with 't'. What are the rules about this word in other varieties of English?

Comment: Schedule is another word that is skedu... in the US, and shedu... in UK...There are many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pronunciation of ‘often’ does not inherently depend on dialect. See: [How should "often" be pronounced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/how-should-often-be-pronounced) (possible duplicate).

Comment: Interesting. I'm pleased to see that I was right to find it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it's a dialect thing. I often hear people pronounce the 't' in 'often'. It annoys me, because I grew up with it silent, but it's not actually *wrong* in any sense.

I'm British, by the way. I hadn't noticed it (the pronounce 't', that is) being an American use at all (but now I probably won't be able to stop noticing it). It seems to be increasing in Britain, though.